# How to name the symbol in a hash automatically?

Tags: ruby, hash, syntax, symbols

I have been making a chess game and I need some help with hashes.  Specifically how do I automatically name a hash table symbol using an iterator 'i'

```
8.times do |i = 0, x = 0|
  i += 1
  x += 1
  pawnHash[:P] = "P#{i}",Pawn.new(x,2,"P#{i}","black")
end
puts pawnHash
```

the symbol should look like this:
`:P1`. But is seems impossible to name a hash using the variable 'i'

The full set of 8 symbols should look like this:  :P1, :P2, :P3 ... etc.
I tried doing `:P + i` when declaring the key/value pair, but I got a syntax error due to the '+' sign.

Comment: When your keys are dynamic like this, it's a clear sign that you shouldn't use symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to make the key a symbol?

You can do `hash["P#{i}".to_sym]`

```
2.0.0-p247 :016 > i = 2
 => 2 
2.0.0-p247 :017 > h = {}
 => {} 
2.0.0-p247 :018 > h["P#{i}".to_sym] = "value"
 => "value" 
2.0.0-p247 :019 > h
 => {:P2=>"value"} 
2.0.0-p247 :020 > h.keys.first.class
 => Symbol
```

Or you can do `:"P#{i}"`

Comment: I forgot about to_sym.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your loop and make it more Ruby-like:

```
pawn_hash = {}
8.times { |i| pawn_hash["P#{ i + 1 }".to_sym] = "P#{ i + 1}" }
pawn_hash 
# => {:P1=>"P1",
#     [...]
#     :P8=>"P8"}
```

You could avoid using `i + 1` by assigning it to an intermediate variable if you want to play the DRY game:

```
pawn_hash = {}
8.times do |i|
  c = i + 1
  pawn_hash["P#{ c }".to_sym] = "P#{ c }"
end 
pawn_hash 
# => {:P1=>"P1",
#     [...]
#     :P8=>"P8"}
```

Or, use a different loop:

```
pawn_hash = {}
1.upto(8) { |i| pawn_hash["P#{ i }".to_sym] = "P#{ i }" }
pawn_hash 
# => {:P1=>"P1",
#     [...]
#     :P8=>"P8"}
```

In Ruby we use snake_case, instead of camelCase, for variable and method names. Classes and Modules get camelCase.

Also, meditate on these:

```
pawn_hash = 8.times.map { |i| ["P#{ i + 1 }".to_sym, "P#{ i + 1}"] }.to_h
# => {:P1=>"P1",
#     :P2=>"P2",
#     :P3=>"P3",
#     :P4=>"P4",
#     :P5=>"P5",
#     :P6=>"P6",
#     :P7=>"P7",
#     :P8=>"P8"}

pawn_hash = Hash[8.times.map { |i| ["P#{ i + 1 }".to_sym, "P#{ i + 1}"] }]
# => {:P1=>"P1",
#     :P2=>"P2",
#     :P3=>"P3",
#     :P4=>"P4",
#     :P5=>"P5",
#     :P6=>"P6",
#     :P7=>"P7",
#     :P8=>"P8"}
#     :P8=>"P8"}
```

It's not necessary to loop and assign to the hash. Instead, it's very Ruby-like to do it all in one pass. The `times` method is an iterator. `map` can iterate over that and will return the block values for each iteration. `to_h` is a more modern way in Ruby to convert an array to a hash, just as is using `Hash[...]`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the alternate syntax on the loop as well.